# What is the Tridion.TopologyManager.Client endpoint

Tags: topology-manager, odata, sites-9

I am trying to setup an application that will allow management of Topology through a Web API to allow the automated creation and mapping of publications.

I can manually use the topology commands through Powershell but want to achieve the same through a .Net API.

Powershell commands are working on this environment and am able to do the equivalent calls I am attempting in the code

Tridion.TopologyManager.Client is the .dll that allows communication to the client and is used by the Powershell commands.

What I am unsure of is the endpoint that this should be connecting to.

There is the SDL Web Topology Manager site setup in out Dev environment on port 81 (http://localhost:81)

When I use this as the base I am getting errors that the client cant connect. This is the error I am getting when attempting to list Websites.

```
An error occurred while processing this request.
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at SJP.Tridion.QualificationImport.TopologyService.GetMapping()
   at SJP.Tridion.QualificationImport.Program.TopologySetup()
```

When attemptint o create website or mapping the client is not throwing any errors but not making any ammends to the topology.

```
_client.AddToWebsites(new WebsiteData()
{
    Id = websiteId,
    CdEnvironmentId = cdEnvironmentId,
    BaseUrls = baseUrls
});
```

I am able to use the http://localhost:81/ttmhealth/check which is returning a 200 OK response.

Wondering if anyone has had any success in using this client. And specifically what the expected endpoint should be.

### Example Code setting up the client

```
var url = "http://localhost:81"    
var serviceUrl = new System.Uri(url);
_client = new TopologyManagerClient(serviceUrl);
```

### Tridion Version

- SDL Web Content Manager Build 9.0.0
- SDL Web Content Manager Explorer - Build 9.0.0.0
- SDL Web Experience Manager - Build 9.0.0.0
- Update Version - 0

Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to find out the endpoint URL is to check the Windows environment variable on the CM server using the following PowerShell command: `get-item env:tridion_ttm_serviceurl`

This should give a value such as: http://localhost:81/ttm201601

---

Here's some code that I used recently on my Tridion Sites 8.5 environment for getting the Client:

```
TopologyManagerClient ttm = new TopologyManagerClient(new Uri("http://localhost:81/ttm201601"))
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "my-password")
};

List<CmEnvironmentData> cmEnvs = ttm.CmEnvironments.ToList()
```

I took a lot of inspiration for my script from Nuno's code here: https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Exploring-Topology-Manager/blob/master/ExploreTopMan/ExploreTopMan/Program.cs

Comment: I did a bit of digging to see where the 'ttm201601' part of the endpoint came from and it appears that this is a configuration setting within `Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.dll`. If you're using Tridion 8.1 then this is `ttm201501`. I've not got the Tridion Sites 9+ DLLs to hand to check those. I don't think that this is a supported API though, so things may need to change if you upgrade Tridion.

Comment: Actually, the Topology Manager (OData) API is considered (semi-)public. That is why it’s versioned (i.e. there is a version number in the URL).

Comment: That’s good to know, Rick. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, Exactly the information that I needed. All working as it should now.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you managed to get it sorted 