# How to get active target types

Tags: core-service, sites-9.1

We have total 4 Target types, Two are Marked Offline "Yes" and Two are Marked Offline "No".
now we are getting all target types using below conde but we need available targets( offline "No") only. How to Get Active targets?

We are using SDL Tridion Sites 9.1

```
TargetTypesFilterData targetTypesFilter = new TargetTypesFilterData();
IEnumerable<TargetTypeData> targetTypes = _client.GetSystemWideList(targetTypesFilter)
.OfType<TargetTypeData>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You would not be able to get the value of a Content Delivery environment's **Marked Offline** property using the Core Service API. You need to be using the `Tridion.TopologyManager.Client` DLL that allows communication with the Topology Manager items. You can find the DLL from the **bin\client\TopologyManager** subfolder of **%TRIDON_HOME%**.

To get the value Marked Offline property on Content Delivery environments, something like this should work:

```
TopologyManagerClient client = new TopologyManagerClient(new Uri("http://localhost:84/ttm201601/"));
client.CdTopologies
      .GetAllPages()
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(t =>
      {
         t.CdEnvironments.ToList().ForEach(e =>
         {
            if ((bool)e.IsOffline)
            {
                // The Marked Offline property is true.
            }
         });
      });
```

For more information on the Tridion.TopologyManager.Client endpoint, this TREX post should help: [What is the Tridion.TopologyManager.Client endpoint](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20829/what-is-the-tridion-topologymanager-client-endpoint).